# Blender Video Editing: How to create custom effect strip?

Tags: scripting, interface, video-sequence-editor, video, effects

I would like to create a custom effect strip for the VSE (Video Sequence Editor) and add it into the Add->Effect Strip menu. In my case I want to create a copy of the Transform effect, except with certain default values (ie. Blend=Over Drop, Scale X=0.75, ...).

How can I go about adding this custom effect?

I understand that blender is scriptable, but I have not found any resources that mention this particular topic. Any pertinent links or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it could be a version of default transform effect that is saved as start up file?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to code an effect and I believe that it is a bit of a challenge. You could use python to code adding a transform effect with those parameters already defined, or you could append this metastrip plus effect fro another "master" blend file scene.

Here I have created a metastrip by adding a color effect (red) then pressing Ctrl-G. To this metastrip I added a transform effect and set the scale and x,y values. I also changed the blend type to "overdrop"

[image: Dupe metastrip]

Next I selected the metastrip and its transform effect and duplicated them with Shift-D. I can place this duplicate metastrip anywhere on the timeline. Press the TAB key to step nside the metastrip and change the media.

[image: Change the source media]

Press the TAB key to get back out to the master sequence timeline, then you can drag the end handle of the metastrip to the correct new length.

[image: Duplicated strip]

Then you could split your screen to make a little FX bin on the side.

[image: FX bin]

This is at timeline -0. In other words, you place a bunch of stuff outside the rendered timeline. Then you can select them no matter where you are in the edited timeline. They wont zoom or move unless you change it. I have also altered the color of that red strip in the other effect so that you can identify the one that you want to use, it may have different x,y offset values or scale etc.

Also you could enable the Addon Extra Sequencer Actions, then use it to copy the transform and blend type properties from your original effect to the others. It is a bit fiddly to select correctly. Make sure the master effect is the last one that you select.